# How to extract a special word from the beginning of values in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There is a column in excel want to extract the word of **the** from the beginning of values. Just the word of **the** must extract.

[image]

Comment: substitute() or left() come to mind.

Comment: @SolarMike, can you do that?

Comment: Worth looking up the functions right(), mid(), find() etc

Comment: Including your own attempt at solving your own issue would make this question on-topic. Asking for people to do the work for you is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

In cell **B1** ... `=IF(C1=A1,"",LEFT(A1,3))`

In cell **C1** ... `=TRIM(IF(LEFT(UPPER(A1),4) = "THE ",MID(A1,4,1000),A1))`

[image: IF]

Just move your references as need be.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
IFERROR(MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)+1,LEN(A2)),A2)

IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)-1),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that you can use :

Cell F1 has the key word you would like to extract out
I have given 3 example ( "the" , "is" , "very")

The logic is

1. Column F I determine if the strings starts with the key word . I use MID and LEN functions. It gives a logical True or false

[Picture-01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QktMa.png)

2. In Column G I show the word to be extracted if the string matches (i.e. Column F is True else a nothing)

[Picture-02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSKG1.png)

3. In Column H I show the rest of the string if the word need to be extracted

[Picture-03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6YzL.png)

This is dynamic . as you change the value in Cell F1 it will show you the extracted data accordingly.

Example 1 : with keyword "the"
[Picture-04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSo2s.png)

Example 2 : with keyword "is"
[Picture-05](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s9sx.png)

Example 3 : with keyword "very" [Picture-06](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXAsq.png)

[Picture-07](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89yNP.png)

Note the Column F is not necessary - you can as well embed this formula into the Column G and Column H formula. I just split it for easier understanding.